# log4cplus RollingFileAppender BAD_ACCESS Error

Tags: c++, ios, multithreading, log4cplus

```
thread #11: tid = 0x82c51, 0x30fc99f8 libsystem_c.dylib`flockfile, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x38)
 frame #0: 0x30fc99f8 libsystem_c.dylib`flockfile
 frame #1: 0x30ffd690 libsystem_c.dylib`fseeko + 60
 frame #2: 0x00205310 `std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::seekoff(long long, std::__1::ios_base::seekdir, unsigned int) + 516
 frame #3: 0x001d8186 `log4cplus::RollingFileAppender::append(log4cplus::spi::InternalLoggingEvent const&) + 746
 frame #4: 0x001c0758 `log4cplus::Appender::doAppend(log4cplus::spi::InternalLoggingEvent const&) + 484
 frame #5: 0x001c232c `log4cplus::helpers::AppenderAttachableImpl::appendLoopOnAppenders(log4cplus::spi::InternalLoggingEvent const&) const + 336
 frame #6: 0x001eea3a `log4cplus::spi::LoggerImpl::callAppenders(log4cplus::spi::InternalLoggingEvent const&) + 138
 frame #7: 0x001eef9e `log4cplus::spi::LoggerImpl::forcedLog(log4cplus::spi::InternalLoggingEvent const&) + 26
 frame #8: 0x001ee200 `log4cplus::Logger::forcedLog(log4cplus::spi::InternalLoggingEvent const&) const + 28
 frame #9: 0x001f0b94 `log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(log4cplus::Logger const&, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, int, char const*) + 160
```

- Above is the log of log4cplus crash in ios App. I had set FileMaxSize = 500Kb and MaxBackUp = 5.
- So, After 5 log File BackUp Taken & When for the 6th Time Going for BackUp Then its Crashing.
- I had made a static Library in which I had made 8 Logger Instance & that All are dumping Log into Same Log File.
- Used MultiThreading Environment

Comment: This looks like the `FILE *` used by the `fstream`'s `filebuf` is `NULL`. I cannot see how that could happen, though.

Comment: @wilx as per my view, it is problem of Multi Threading Environment Lock Acquiring issue.

Comment: Is it possible that you have not linked with equivalent of `-pthread` on MacOS X?

Comment: in log4cplus its Not Mentioned that i had to link -pthread.

Comment: In theory, you should not need to do anything. However, I do not have a way of testing log4cplus on MacOS X.

Comment: Same Thing Works on Android.. Strange!!! However in .Properties File, i had Mentioned To Consider File Locking Mechanism.

Comment: The file locking that log4cplus uses to lock the log files access should use separate "lock file." In any case, worst case, you should get a deadlock, not a NULL pointer dereference in C library.

Comment: @wilx: i had used https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus/blob/master/iOS/scripts/cmake_ios_armv7.sh script to build for ios. need Any Changes??

Comment: @wilx -DLOG4CPLUS_SINGLE_THREADED="TRUE" Macro Seems for Single Thread, Can i Get Macro for MultiThread.

Comment: @wilx When MaxSize of a File Reached, Then File Pointer should Point to Another File to Write Log, This Works upto Max No of BackUp File Reached. After That File Pointer Points to the First File & Write Logs into it. as First File MaxSize Reached then File Pointer is Unable to Point to Second File as of BackUp Algorithm.. Hope You Got Exact Scenario..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89677/discussion-between-nishant-b9-and-wilx).